# S3: downloading files with "@" (at symbol) (at sign) in the filename

Tags: amazon-s3, urlencode

I have a bunch of files with "@" sign in them. I've uploaded them to S3 and I wish to serve them to my mobile client. However, because AWS url-encodes the '@' sign, the path to the file is no longer what I originally uploaded.

for example:

I uploaded:
`<...>/mybuckt-static/brand_img/ios/giftCard@2x.png`

but the download path now is:
`<...>/mybucket-static/brand_img/ios/giftCard%402x.png`

so. is it possible to keep using the original filename (without escaping it first?)

Answer (score 1):

so, yes, there's a solution. its detailed here: https://medium.com/in-the-weeds/handling-url-encoded-s3-file-names-6fa54ea35f55

but the crux of it is this: set the content-disposition metadata on the file to the original filename and you're all set. here's some cli-based code that does that (and makes the files public):

```
aws s3 ls s3://mybucket/brand_img/ios/|awk {'print $4'} > objects.txt

while read line; do aws s3api copy-object --bucket mybucket  \
--copy-source /mybucket/brand_img/ios/$line --key brand_img/ios/$line \
--metadata-directive REPLACE --metadata Content-Disposition=$line --acl public-read; done < objects.txt
```